# Better Solution for Finding out Maximums for Consecutive Array Subsequences

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose, given an integer array A, I want to find out another COUNT array using A.

e.g., int A[] = {34, 10, 15, 14, 30, 27, 21, 32, 50}

For above example, COUNT[] should be: {0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 8}

Here, COUNT[i] corresponds to A[i] and COUNT[i] represents the number of consecutive previous elements of A which are less than A[i].

e.g., A[1] = 10, COUNT[1] = 0, because there's no previous element in A which is less than A[1].

A[7] = 32, COUNT[7] = 6, because 32 is greater than previous 6 continuous elements (e.g., 10, 15, 14, 30, 27, 21).

Can we have O(n) solution for this problem?

**EDIT:**

As per @user1990169's algorithm,
I implemented it in Java as following, but it's not giving expected output as algorithm doesn't count those indices which are not present on stack (already popped out in earlier iteration).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    // int a[] = new int[] { 53, 2, 7, 5, 15, 12, 10, 38, 72 };
    int a[] = new int[] { 34, 10, 15, 14, 30, 27, 21, 32, 50 };

    int N = a.length;

    int[] count = new int[N];

    int tos = 0;
    int poppedElemIdx = 0;
    int popCount = 0;

    boolean counted = false;

    stack.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        popCount = 0;
        counted = false;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {

            tos = stack.peek();

            if (a[tos] > a[i]) {

                stack.push(i);
                count[i] = count[poppedElemIdx] + popCount;
                counted = true;
                break;

            }

            poppedElemIdx = stack.pop();
            popCount++;
            // popCount += (count[poppedElemIdx] + 1);

        }

        if (counted) {
            continue;
        }

        stack.push(i);
        count[i] = popCount;

    }

    // Print count array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.print(count[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(N) Space and O(N) Time complexity algorithm.

Traverse the array from left to right. Maintain an external stack of elements.

```
A[0] = 34, push 34 onto stack. Count[0] = 0.  
A[1] = 10,  
Now keep popping out from stack till either it is empty 
or you encounter a number greater than the current element (10). 
Here 34 is > 10, hence we push 10 onto stack and make Count[1] = 0.  

A[2] = 15.  
So we pop out 10 from the stack, push 15 onto stack,  
and make Count[2] = Count[ last popped out index ] + Number of indices popped out  
                  = 0 + 1 = 1.  
A[3] = 14.
So we push 14 onto stack and make Count[3] = 0.
A[4] = 30.
So we pop out 14 and 15 from the array, push 30 onto the array 
and make Count[4] = Count[ index of 15 ] + Number of indices popped out(2) 
                  = 1 + 2 = 3.
```

Do this till you reach the end of array.

Since each item is pushed exactly once and popped out exactly once from the stack, the time complexity is O( 2*N) = O(N).

**EDIT: As suggested, it will be better if you store the indices in the stack, instead of values.**

Comment: +1 very good solution. You can push indices instead of values in the stack. Also I understand what you mean by `Count[ last popped out index ] + Number of indices popped out` but a bit more details for the other readers will be of help.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thanks. Elaborated my algorithm to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user1990169. U just solved Stock Profit Maximization problem (unknowingly) :D

Comment: @user1990169, There seems some bug in your mentioned algorithm or I didn't understand it properly, could u please tell me what's wrong with my code (see EDIT part of question)?

Comment: @user1990169, After some small changes in logic, code is working fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Working program after small modifications into original algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    int a[] = new int[] { 53, 2, 7, 5, 15, 12, 10, 38, 72 };
    // int a[] = new int[] { 34, 10, 15, 14, 30, 27, 21, 32, 50 };

    int N = a.length;

    int[] count = new int[N];

    int tos = 0;
    int poppedElemIdx = 0;
    int popCount = 0;

    boolean counted = false;

    stack.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        popCount = 0;
        counted = false;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {

            tos = stack.peek();

            if (a[tos] > a[i]) {

                stack.push(i);
                count[i] = popCount;
                counted = true;
                break;

            }

            poppedElemIdx = stack.pop();
            popCount += (count[poppedElemIdx] + 1);

        }

        if (counted) {
            continue;
        }

        stack.push(i);
        count[i] = popCount;

    }

    // Print count array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        System.out.print(count[i] + " ");
    }

}
```